# PHP - Shared Hosting: SOAP 1.2 upgrade.

Tags: php, function, class, soap

so I am completely new to this SOAP thing but I am trying to use magento with VendHQ using plugin called VortexHQ which requires website to support SOAP 1.2, I am currently on 1.1, my hosting company said:

"I consulted with our system administrators and here is their reply:

The soap protocol comes in two versions - 1.1 and 1.2. The PHP classes SoapClient and SoapServer in all php versions after 5.0.1 support both protocols. The programmer decides which version to use. For reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Best Regards,"

I don't understand what they are saying, do they mean like I have to code new PHP file? Can someone help out please?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably a little too broad, but let me explain a little about SOAP.  SOAP is like a envelope that you put mail in and then send the mail.  They have different varieties available (square, rectangle, etc).  Mailboxes however only accept one type of envelope, so if you try and send mail in the wrong envelope your message will never reach the person.  That is just like 1.1 and 1.2.  They do the exact same thing, but are just slightly different formats.  If you send the wrong format, it will throw an error.

Now on to what these people replied.  The server can send ***any*** type of envelope/SOAP request.  Using the analogy above, the server holds only an endless supply of paper for you to make envelopes with.  You/the programmer has to take the paper and fold it into the proper envelope and then put in the proper content.  The server admins are saying that PHP allows you specify which protocol you are using, meaning the programmer can choose to make a SOAP request with 1.1 or 1.2.

Now on to your final question, how do you connect the two apps you are using?  I have no idea.  If they connect via SOAP, then you probably don't need to do much, just point one app at the other.  The question you will need to ask will be just how to connect the two applications, and you probably don't need to concern yourself over SOAP protocols and support.  I would imagine there is a configuration option inside one of the program to switch between SOAP versions.

Comment: The way it works is:
I go on a 3rd party website, and I specify connection settings for Magento and VendHQ stores, then I click "SYNC" and it starts sending data between each other, but I receive error and that error says that I have wrong Soap version, so does it mean that my hosting company is lying about Soap 1.2 support?

Comment: No.  Your company is correct.  Magento has the wrong SOAP version or VendHQ has the wrong SOAP version.  SOAP has nothing to do with the server itself.